# What are events in structured logs?

Tags: python, structured-logging

I'd like to know what events are in structured logs. 
Can only events trigger the different processors?
I have tried looking up on python docs, but could not find more information regarding what constitutes as an event.

Comment: Are you asking about the events and processors in [structlog](http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/)?